# Mobile Safari "hover" (x positon of finger matches x position of image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I'm working on a web app where I don't really have web hooks for hovers (think touch device). I can get x coords of exactly where the mouse is at all times.

I need to check to see if the x coords of the mouse is over top of an image, and then grab that image I'm over top of.

**What I'm doing**

I'm using jQuery right now, and what I do is setup an array (**imgCoords**) of the **offset.left** value of each image. I then use

```
imgCoords.indexOf(mousePosition.x);
```

(mousePosition.x) is made up, but you get the idea.

I use the above code to grab the image that matches that returned index

```
fingerCoordToImgIndex = imgCoords.indexOf(mousePosition.x);
$('img').eq(fingerCoordToImgIndex).css({'stuff'});
```

This only works for the initial entry of mouse over image though (finger x only matches image x, not image x + width), and seems inefficient. I think I could thrash around a little longer to get it right, but I'd love it if one of you pro's could rescue me =p

Thanks tons!
-Ken

Comment: If it helps, the images I'm "Hovering" have a set width, so I can get a range of **finger.x** is over **x** through **x+width**.

Comment: One more, here's the JS I'm using during the touchmove event:

http://pastie.org/838253

Edit: Pastied because I can't use markdown in the comments or I'm just not doing it right lol.